# Effective ways to load data from hdfs to local system?

Tags: hadoop, hdfs, bigdata

I'm trying to load terabytes of data from hdfs to local using hadoop fs -get but it takes hours to complete this task. Is there an alternate effective way to get data from hdfs to local?

Answer (score 5):

How fast you copy to a local filesystem is dependent on many factors including:

1. Are you copying in parallel or in serial.
2. Is the file splittable (can a mapper potentially deal with a block of data rather than a file, usually a problem if you have certain kinds of compressed files on HDFS)
3. Network bandwidth of course because you will likely be pulling from many DataNodes

**Option 1: DistCp**

In any case, since you state your files are on HDFS, we know each hadoop slave node can see the data. You can try to use the DistCp command (distributed copy) which will make your copy operation into a parallel MapReduce job for you WITH ONE MAJOR CAVEAT!.

MAJOR CAVEAT: This will be a distributed copy process so the destination you specify on the command line needs to be a place visible to all nodes. To do this you can mount a network share on all nodes and specify a directory in that network share (NFS, Samba, Other) as the destination for your files. This may take getting a system admin involved, but the result *may* be a faster file copy operation so the cost-benefit is up to you.

DistCp documentation is here: http://hadoop.apache.org/docs/r0.19.0/distcp.html

DistCp example: YourShell> hadoop distcp -i -update /path/on/hdfs/to/directoryOrFileToCopy file:///LocalpathToCopyTo

**Option 2:** Multi-threaded Java Application with HDFS API
As you found, the hadoop fs -get is a sequential operation. If your java skills are up to the task, you can write your own multithreaded copy program using the hadoop file system API calls.

**Option 3:** Multi-threaded Program in any language with HDFS REST API
If you know a different language than Java, you can similarly write a multi-threaded program that accesses HDFS through the [HDFS REST API](http://hadoop.apache.org/docs/stable/hadoop-project-dist/hadoop-hdfs/WebHDFS.html) or as an [NFS mount](http://hadoop.apache.org/docs/stable/hadoop-project-dist/hadoop-hdfs/HdfsNfsGateway.html)

Comment: Very good explanation regarding the caveat of DistCp, I did not know about that.